# how to scale an object that uses a mirror modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, scale

Hope you can help

I have applied a mirror modifier to the below. However - how I can make it so that it mirrors the same result, but on the y and z axis?

[image]

Also I am having problems when scaling to make the object more narrow. The first image below is what I want:

[image]

However instead of scaling, it seems to just move the object around as though they are two seperate objects (see below). The only way I created the desired effect above was through using clipping, although the tutorial I am following does not use clipping and I don't want to run into any more serious issues down the line...

[image]

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mirror modifier uses the Origin of the object as the axis of symmetry.

If you scale the object using median point then you will be creating a gap in the object, as the geometry will be moving away from the object's origin.

[image]

What you need to do is [**snap**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html?highlight=snap) the 3d cursor to the object's origin and use the cursor as the pivot center for transformations.

In Object mode press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and select "Cursor to Selected"

The 3d Cursor will move to the object's origin.

Then in edit mode select the [3D cursor as the Pivot Point](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/3d_cursor.html).

Scaling will be done from the objects origin.

[image]

For more info read: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/index.html?highlight=pivot%20point

Answer (score 1):

When are you scaling the object you have selected all vertex, all faces so it's scaling through the all plane which is not yet connected to the mirror object. It's ok to use clip checkbox and deselect it after apply every change you want to. To the first question - you've also checkbox "Y" below "X" in the modifier.

Answer (score 0):

This is from experience. I will provide a link for a basic cheat sheet from BlenderGuru. This is his cheat sheet that he created.

For scaling or rotating:

select the area you are wanting to scale
g - to grab that area
 g then x constrains motion Left and Right
 g then y constrains motion Forward and Backward
 g then z constrains motion Up and Down

there is an arrow where your mouse is...move in to make the object smaller; move out to make the object bigger.
If you already know this, sorry for making you feel a certain way. 
Great mesh by the way!!!! I love it!

Here is that link: http://download.blender.org/documentation/BlenderHotkeyReference.pdf